# Accessing Redis in a peered VNet

Tags: azure, redis, azure-networking

I have an IaaS server in one Azure VNet and a premium Redis cache in another peered VNet. There are no NSGs. I can't access Redis using redis-cli. Is there some restriction to accessing Redis from a peered VNet in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to have "allow traffic to transit" switched on, even though logically it's not transit traffic. TIL.

Comment: Where did you find this setting?

Answer (score 0):

There is no policy-based restriction but there are likely physical ports that need to be opened up. Can you please review the Outbound and Inbound port requirements:

[Outbound port requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-vnet#outbound-port-requirements)
[Inbound port requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-vnet#inbound-port-requirements)

[Additional VNET network connectivity requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-vnet#additional-vnet-network-connectivity-requirements)